# Calculating the christoffel coefficients

Tags: differential-geometry

Given the surface parametrized by $$\phi (u,v)=(u\space\text{sin}(v),u\space\text{cos}(v),v)$$
I am asked to calculate the christoffel coefficients. I know these coefficients can be calculated with some formulas that only use the coefficients of the first fundamental form, but I want to understand the following way of calulating them, (this is the solution to the problem):

Computing the first derivatives and second we have:

[image]

[image]

Where N is the normal vector. From where it is easy to see that [image]

Up until this point I understand everything. What I don't understand is what follows:

[image]

[image]

To begin with, my computation of $\phi_{uu}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}N$ is different, I have $\phi_{uu}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}N=(\text{sin}(v)(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}),\text{cos}(v)(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}),\frac{-u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}})$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\varphi_{uv} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + u^2}} \vec{N} = \frac{1}{1 + u^2}(-u^2 \sin(v) - \sin(v), u^2 \cos(v) + \cos(v), 0) + \frac{1}{1 + u^2}(\sin(v), -\cos(v),u)$

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof where do the $u^2$ come from? neither N or $\varphi$ have them

Comment: If you add a factor in the denominator, you have to add it in the numerator too.